# Android: BluetoothSocket readLine timeout

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, timeout

I should insert a timeout on a readLine for a bluetooth input stream.

```
    BluetoothDevice device = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
            .getRemoteDevice("00:00:00:00:00:00");

    sock = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
            .fromString(insecureUUID));
    sock.connect();

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    String line = in.readLine(); //if no answer from device..i'll wait here forever

    do { [...]

    } while ((line = in.readLine()) != null);
```

The connection works fine, but i've got a bluetooth serial converter linked to another device. If the second one is turned off i'll wait forever on the readLine. Any chance i can throw an exception or a timeout?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and i solved it by creating a ResponderThread that extends Thread. This thread waits a certain amount of time and after that it checks if the input stream variable have changed.

```
try {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            bluetoothSocket.getInputStream()));

    responderThread = new ResponderThread(bluetoothSocket, ACCESS_RESPONSE);
    responderThread.start();
    response= bufferedReader.read();

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // Handle the exception.
}
```

In my case the responderThread closes the socket if there is no response within 3 seconds and the execution goes into the catch block of the class where i create the responderThread. Then the exception is handled.